# How to make this .html reveal slowly and then hide slowly on mouse over and out

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've tried so many different ways of doing this, but I cannot manage to make this `.html` appear smoothly using jQuery...

I cannot put the iframe in the HTML and then hide it and reveal it using CSS because I have several iframes that will appear in the preview window, so I must call the code when a user rolls over a certain section.

```
    var version11 = $('#version11');
    var previewWindow1 = $("#previewWindow1");

    version11.mouseover(function() {

        previewWindow1.html("<iframe src=\"URL"></iframe>");                            

                                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a hidden container and then call animate on it.

```
<div id="clickme">Click me!</div>
<div id="test" style="display:none">
    Your html dynamic content... 
        Your html dynamic content... 
    Your html dynamic content... 
        Your html dynamic content... 
</div>

$("#clickme").click(function() {    
  $('#test').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle'   
  }, 1500, function() {
  });
});
```

More info at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b8RNU/

Comment: This can't work because I have several iframes that will appear in the same preview area, so I need to call the code when a user rolls over one of the buttons

Comment: Is target page in the same domain as calling page?

Comment: Then you don't need an iframe, you can use jQuery.load function and then call jQuery.fadeIn in callback. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/RSdFk/

Comment: but the html file is in another folder on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Put the iframe in your html and use CSS to set display:none;. Then use jQuery to fade it in. If you add it via jQuery, the content won't have loaded yet, and it will look crap.

Comment: This can't work because I have several iframes that will appear in the same preview area, so I need to call the code when a user rolls over one of the buttons.

Comment: You could use the .load() method to only show it once it had loaded?

Comment: When you only post the code you have, it's impossible to guess what you are doing. Two of us here are telling you the same thing, and you are saying it's wrong, but with no indication of what you are actually doing. If you have the html in a folder on the same server, just use load(), no iframe needed.